# Com faço para repetir uma frase que o usuário digitou em n vezes no js?

Tags: javascript

Meu código que não está funcionando, como faço pra repetir a frase que o usuário digitou?

Por que o que eu fiz não está dando certo?

Como é uma questão da faculdade, preciso resolve-lá com o laço for.

[[image: [1]]

Comment: pode explicar melhor o problema??

Comment: poste seu código e não imagens do mesmo... nao podemos editar ou copiar caso tenha algo errado...

Comment: Bem-vindo João Vitor Lumertz, se uma resposta resolver seu problema marque-a como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079. Esse tour tb é interessante https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. No mais boa navegação!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função **repeat**:

```js
var palavra = "oi";
var quantidade = 10;

alert(palavra.repeat(quantidade));
```

No trecho do seu código, ficaria assim (adapte conforme sua necessidade):

```js
var i;
var nome = prompt("Digite qualquer nome:");
var q = prompt("Informe a quantidade de vezes que você quer que repita:");
q = parseFloat(q);

alert(nome.repeat(q));
```

Usando `for`:

```js
var i;
var nome = prompt("Digite qualquer nome:");
var q = prompt("Informe a quantidade de vezes que você quer que repita:");
q = parseFloat(q);

var resultado = "";

for (var i = 1; i <= q; i++)
{
 resultado += nome;

}

alert(resultado);
```

Comment: Essa é uma questão da faculdade e preciso resolve-lá com o for.

Comment: adicionei com o uso do For. Mas se é questão de faculdade, tente estudar pra entender o  erro e qual parte do codigo está tendo dificuldade

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: blza se resolveu, por favor, marca como resolvido a resposta. obrigada.

Answer (score 3):

> A instrução for cria um loop que consiste em três expressões opcionais, dentro de parênteses e separadas por ponto e vírgula, seguidas por uma declaração ou uma sequência de declarações executadas em sequência.

```
for (inicilização; condição; incremento) {
    // código que será repetido
}
```

### Por que o que eu fiz não está dando certo?

<sub>Como é uma questão da faculdade, preciso resolve-lá com o laço for.</sub>

> Repare que na `inicialização` do seu loop `for` você faz `i<0` condição essa que não existe. Para tal você deveria declarar a variável `i` como sendo `negativa`, por exemplo `-2` e, nesse caso, o loop seria executado de `-2` até o numero anterior ao informado no prompt, ou seja, `i<q`.

Veja no exemplo a seguir o passo a passo do código sendo executado com a variável `i` sendo declarada negativa.

```js
    var i =-2;
    var nome = prompt("Digite qualquer nome:");
    var q = prompt("Informe a quantidade de vezes que você quer que repita:");

    for(i<0; i<q; i++){
      console.log( i + " " + nome);
    }
```

ou inicializando dessa forma  `for(i=-2; i<q; i++){`, isto é, de i = -2 até o valor imediatamente inferior ao informado no prompt

```js
    var i;
    var nome = prompt("Digite qualquer nome:");
    var q = prompt("Informe a quantidade de vezes que você quer que repita:");

    for(i=-2; i<q; i++){
      console.log( i + " " + nome);
    }
```

> **Para que seu código execute exatamente o numero de vezes digitado no prompt, altere a inicialização para `i=0`**

```js
var i;
var nome = prompt("Digite qualquer nome:");
var q = prompt("Informe a quantidade de vezes que você quer que repita:");

for(i=0; i<q; i++){
  alert(nome);
}
```